# Validate Stripe expiry date

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Stripe for payment processing. I want to validate the card date whether it is expired or not. The date format should be 1-12 months/upcoming years.

For example: **11/19**, **12/18**, **08/21**, **01/20**

Controller:

```
$exp = explode( '/', Input::get( 'card_expiry' ) );
if ( ( $exp[0] <= 12 ) && $exp[0] > 0 && ( is_int( $exp[1] ) ) ) {

} else {
    return back()->withErrors( 'Add a valid card expiry date' );
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Expiry</label>
    {{ Form::text('card_expiry', '', [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'MM/YY' , 'data-parsley-maxlength'=>"5",'required'=>'' ]) }}
    @if($errors->first('card_expiry'))
    <div class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('card_expiry') }}</div>
    @endif
</div>
```

I tried the above code but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize the **Carbon** library that is packaged with Laravel.

Try the following code:

```
try {
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/y', Input::get('card_expiry'));
    if ($date->isFuture()) {

    } else {
        return back()
                  ->withErrors( 'Add a valid card expiry date' );
    }
} catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    return back()
               ->withErrors('The expiration date does not seem to be a valid month/year');
}
```